# A sequence that always reaches 1

Tags: number-theory

If you take any number $n\in\Bbb N$ and do the following

- $n\mapsto n/2$, if $n$ is even
- $n\mapsto 3n+1$, if $n$ is odd

Then, you get a sequence of positive integers. For example,
$$13\mapsto 40 \mapsto 20 \mapsto 10 \mapsto 5 \mapsto 16 \mapsto 8 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 2 \mapsto 1.$$
It looks like no matter what number we start with, we always eventually reach $1$. Is that a known fact? How can we prove it?

Comment: This is well known and unsolved:  [Collatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)

Comment: If you can then your place in the list of the name of mathematicians that have proved an open problem is certain. You may want to google "Collatz Conjecture"

Comment: So a conjecture is like something we believe must be true but no one has been able to prove?

Comment: I'd say that was too strong a description.  Conjectures, even famous ones, have sometimes proved to be false.  Fermat conjectured that $2^{2^n}+1$ was always prime.  Euler conjectured that, for $n>2$, it took at least $n$ $n^{th}$-powers to sum to an $n^{th}$ power, and so on.